# AWS DynamoDB - ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, conditional-operator

DynamoDB table contains **5** rows, where *parkingSpot* is the primary key.

```
const params = {
  TableName: "gofore-park",
  Item: {
    parkingSpot: {
      N: parkingSpot,
    },
    VRN: {
      S: vrn,
    },
    startTime: {
      S: startTime,
    },
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":empty": {
      S: "",
    },
  },
  ConditionExpression: "VRN = :empty",
};

dynamodb.putItem(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // an error occurred
    console.log(err);
    callback("parking spot is busy");
  } else {
    // successful response
    callback(null, { message: "car parking info is logged" });
  }
});
```

I defined an *ExpressionAttributeValues* to throw an error when trying to putItem when VRN field is not empty.

First, is there a better way to define this condition?

Secondly, I am testing two scenarios with putItem:

1. Update an exisiting row when VRN field is not empty.
   As expected, I get "ConditionalCheckFailedException".
   [image]
2. I do not understand why I get the same error when trying to create a new entry with parkingSpot>5.

   [image]

I've enabled CloudWatch to trace the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is based on the server side item, not the client side. I'd you want to do checks on the client side attributes, then do so using conditions in your code, not in your DynamoDB request.

It makes sense that your condition fails in both scenarios, as the server side items does not equal an empty string in both circumstances.